# Twitch discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py, twitch

Hello I'm trying to code a bot with **discord.py** to notify my discord server when I'm in stream, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if prev.channel and cur.channel:  
         if prev.self_stream != cur.self_stream:
            print("User's self-stream updated!")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask has a great guide on how to ask questions.  What code have you tried?  Let us see what you want.

Comment: the discord.py documentation has what you're looking for [discord.Member.activity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.activities)

Comment: @PaulBrennan this is my code but It dont work

Comment: @jjoy I don't understand what I have to do with that can you help me

Comment: Instead of using `on_voice_state_update`, you can use [`on_member_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member#discord.on_member_update).

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
YourID = #Enter your id here

@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, prev, cur):
    if cur.self_stream and bool(cur.channel) and member.id == YourID:
        print ("User's self stream updated")
```

I hope this may be of help.

Comment: From where are you exactly getting the `message` variable in `process_commands`? And why are you even using it? It's not the `on_message` event